# PyInstaller: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: with ciscoconfparse library

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, ciscoconfparse

I created an .exe of my python code using pyinstaller and it was working fine. But after importing this specific package "from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
", pyinstaller is able to create the .exe but when i execute the .exe it throws an error message

[Please see this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajuxd.png)

I tried to do the workaround as mentioned in some other posts but none seem to work and this problem is seen only when i use ciscoconfparse module.

Please help how can i get around this problem, it is important to use this module.

Comment: According to the traceback, I think you'll need to add the ciscoconfparse `version` file; see https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

Comment: Thanks @AKX,

I created a spec file using 

C:\Python27\Scripts>pyi-makespec --onefile "RR Config Scrub_v1.py"
wrote C:\Python27\Scripts\RR Config Scrub_v1.spec
now run pyinstaller.py to build the executable

Comment: # -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['RR Config Scrub_v1.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Python27\\Scripts'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ciscoconfparse\version'), 'ciscoconfparse'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],

I still get the same error
Please guide with exact steps of including the version file in .exe

Comment: for make a file to exec , you must first makespec : python Makespec.py --noconsole --onefile file.py , then you use Build.py : python Build.py file/file.py , you will find your file in file/dist/file.exe

Comment: The real question is what do i need to put into the spec file to make it work ? Creating a new spec file is pyi-makespec [--onefile] yourprogram.py as per documentation....... What part of spec file do i need to modify so that i can proceed further.

Comment: @AKX

Thanks for your help in guiding in the correct direction, i have this finally working correctly. This is what i had to do to make it work.

datas=[ ( 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ciscoconfparse*', 'ciscoconfparse' ) ],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folling this link https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle by @AKX

I created a spec file and added these two lines in the spec file

```
         datas=[(  'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ciscoconfparse\*', 'ciscoconfparse' ) ],
         hiddenimports=['ciscoconfparse'],
```

and then compiled this into an .exe using the spec file

pyinstaller --clean -y --onefile "RR Config Scrub_v1.spec"

Issue resolved